# When And How to Use Conductors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

The [Caliburn Documentation](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition) on conductors and composition is a little confusing to me.

First, it is not clear to me when one should use a conductor (and when using a conductor, what type). My impression is that a conductor can activate/toggle between different components (with their own view/viewModels) of a parent view/viewModel. Assuming this is correct, why should one use a conductor and activate/deactivate, as opposed to having something like `<ContentControl x:Name="Whatever"></ContentControl>`that is bound to a field in the parent view model?

It is also not really clear to me the proper way to use the AllActive conductor.

To summarize, what I am asking for is a better explanation of when to use conductors, and when/how to use each conductor type.

Comment: A `ContentControl` is a control in the view that may be bound to a property of a conductor. You don't use one or the other.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. One _could_ use one or the other. Once could have a view model, and in that view model have a property that is another view model, and bind that view model to a contentControl. Just as one could also Activate/Deactivate, and bind the contentControl to `x:Name="ActiveItem"`. Does that make sense? So my question is, why should one choose the latter approach?

Comment: Because it's easier an by convention in Caliburn.Micro.